# WPF resizing rectangles proportionally to image

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an image and a list of coordinates that I have to draw on the image, just like a map. All the geometric figures of the coordinates like x, y, width, height is all set according to original size of the image.

I have to draw the image, but its actual size is not fixed. So I want to draw the coordinates on the image and make it resized according to the image ratio to fit into the exact point I intended.

I am trying to align the image to center both horizontally and vertically, so I also have to consider the left and top of the image itself.

My first program was coded in Winforms, so I wrote `Resize` event that calculates ratio, left and top of `PicutreBox` and applied it to every rectangles I drew.

```
myRectangle.left = myImage.left + x * myImage.ratio
```

And the program worked as I intended.

Now I am trying to rewrite the same program with WPF, and I don't know how to solve the problem without ruining the MVVM pattern. I managed to create Rectangles with DataBinding, but binding width / height / left / top to Image is confusing me. Should I just do the same thing that I did in the Winforms? Or is there any ways that I can do what I intend without ruining the pattern?

Answer (score 1):

You can put the image as background of a `Canvas`, and have it resized in a `ViewBox`:

```
<Viewbox>
  <Grid>
    <Canvas Background="{Binding Image}" Loaded="IndicCanvasLoaded"/>
  </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

The "Canvas in a Grid in a ViewBox" makes the Canvas as big as possible, with the correct proportions but still fitting inside the ViewBox (of which you define the apparent size in your Window/Control).

In the ViewModel, you need a `Brush Image {get;set;}` that will receive you bitmap image, and you store a `Canvas IndicCanvas {get;set;}` reference where you can add/remove/manage children (ellipses, rectangles etc).
For instance you can add points/circles with `Ellipse` this way:

```
public void AddToImage(Ellipse e, double x, double y)
{
    IndicCanvas.Children.Add(shc.IndicPoint);
    Canvas.SetLeft(e, x * Scale - ellipseHalfWidth);
    Canvas.SetTop(e, y * Scale - ellipseHalfWidth);
}

public double Scale {get;set;} // uniform scale for x and y axis
```

You connect in the code-behind (View.xaml.cs)

```
private void IndicCanvasLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    => ViewModel.IndicCanvas = (Canvas)sender;
```

and define your ViewModel in the code-behind:

```
public IViewModel ViewModel
{
    get { return (IViewModel) DataContext; }
    set { DataContext = value; }
}
```

that you inject via the code-behind's constructor:

```
public View(IViewModel vm)
{
   ViewModel = vm;
   InitializeComponent();
}
```

In order to have a loosely coupled View/ViewModel, you use an interface `IViewModel`

```
IViewModel { Canvas IndicCanvas; }
```

This way you respect MVVM, and inject dependencies (in the View as well as in the ViewModel) with a container (of your choice), and have a testable ViewModel.

You should have your root composition in App.xamls.cs (using DryIoc in this example):

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public Container DryContainer{ get; set; }
            public App()
    {
        DryContainer = new Container(rules
            => rules.WithoutThrowOnRegisteringDisposableTransient());
        DryContainer.Register<IViewModel, ViewModel>();
        DryContainer.Register<View>();
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        => DryContainer.Resolve<View>().Show();
}
```

(and don't forget to remove in App.xaml `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` or else you'll have two windows, and an error if you do not have a default View constructor)